# Theoretical question regarding unbounded solutions to a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am lost regarding the following question:

Let $a$ and $b$ be real numbers. It is known that the function $y''+ay'+by=\sin(x)$ has a solution that is a non-bounded function. It is also known that the difference between any two solutions is a bounded function all across $\mathbb{R}$. Find $a$ and $b$. Carefully explain each one of your considerations.

I understand that this has to do with $a^2-4b>0$ so that the homogenous solution comes out non-bounded. Also, $a$ should not be equal to $0$, for the formula computing the roots to come out defined. Beyond that point (and particularly regarding the "difference between any two solutions"), I do not understand where I am supposed to take it to… Many thanks!

Comment: You want the homogeneous equation to have only bounded solutions on $\mathbb R$. This should imply that $a = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic equation $$\lambda ^2 +a\lambda +b =0$$ has to have pure imaginary solutions for the homogeneous solution to be bounded and the general solution to be unbounded.

Thus you have to have $$a=0$$ and $b=1$

The equation $$y''+y=\sin x$$ has its general solution as $$ y=C_1 \sin x + C_2 \cos x -(1/2)x\cos x$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I have two questions, though: 1. maybe I am misunderstanding the wording of the question, but the difference between C2cosx and -(1/2)xcosx is unbounded, whereas it says  that the difference between any two solutions is a bounded function. Am I just misreading it? 2. I see that the solution is correct, but how did you logically derive that a had to be 0 and b had to be 1?

Comment: Note that $C_2 cos x$ by itself is not a solution.

Comment: Ok, so they meant difference between the full solutions. It means I was misreading it. What about the second bit:  how did you logically derive that a had to be 0 and b had to be 1?

Comment: I understand that that a=0 and b=1 means that the root comes out at +/-i, but why can it not be the case with other imaginary roots?

Comment: You want the force $\sin x$ to be the solution to the homogeneous solution so you get the unbounded $x\sin x$ as your particular solution.